# Run EF Core migration with pulumi

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, deployment, pulumi

How can I run a SQL script after creating a database with pulumi? Also how to run EF migrations with pulumi?

I have created an Azure SQL Server using https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure/sql/sqlserver/

```
public SqlServer(string name, SqlServerArgs args, CustomResourceOptions? opts = null)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

When creating a SQL Server, you can capture the output connection string and use 
maybe [Dynamic Providers](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/programming-model/#dynamicproviders) to execute custom code linked to that resource (SQL Server).

However, it seems that Dynamic Providers are not yet aupported in C#.